# Calculating user's balance with multiple cost tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, accounting

We're building a SaaS offering where a user can incur costs from various types of transactions for example:

- Making phone calls
- Sending SMS messages
- Storing audio recordings

We have built our system to store the costs of each service, for example the `call_audit` table looks like:

```
Date       Call ID  Our Cost  User Cost Currency Duration User ID
---------- -------- --------- --------- -------- -------- -------
2018-01-02 sm_123   0.01      0.02      USD      72       us_1
```

The `sms_audit` table looks like:

```
Date       SMS ID   Our Cost  User Cost Currency User ID
---------- -------- --------- --------- -------- -------
2018-01-02 sm_123   0.01      0.02      USD      us_1
```

Then there is a `payment_audit` table with user payments and refunds:

```
Date       User ID  Amount Currency Type 
---------- -------- ------ -------- ----
2018-01-02 us_1     12     USD      CHARGE
2018-01-02 us_1     -2     USD      REFUND
```

We also have a `user` table with a `balance` column which we decrement when the user incurs a call, sms cost or refund. We increment it when the user pays into their account (`CHARGE` as above).

But going forward I'm thinking we need something more resilient than a single balance figure which gets updated in code.

One improvement is to update the balance figure with triggers instead of in code.

Another approach would be to calculate the user's total costs and payments across multiple tables and sum the lot. As the tables grow to many 1000s of transactions I can imagine this becoming a slow computation.

Another approach we thought of was to have a `balance_transactions` table with a `debit`, `credit` and running `balance` column. This of course incurs transitive dependencies between rows which isn't great if seeking a nicely normalized DB. It also means we're duplicating data, but in the real world is this an acceptable trade off?

Comment: If I were designing such a system, I would focus on storing each atomic transaction as a separate row in a table, with no updates.  I would then figure out how to get the reporting that I need from that table -- or perhaps if necessary what enhancements then need to be made.

Comment: @GordonLinoff exactly our thoughts, hence why we call these tables _call_audit_ and _payment_audit_ tables. The table rows are read only once all the entries committed. What sort of approach would you use to obtain *'reporting'* on the audit tables?

Comment: . . A query that combined the results, presumably using `union all`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid duplicating the data by using materialized views. Note, that updating the balance (in any way - either by the application, triggers, partial running balances) **already** duplicates the data. As such, you should have some validation procedures running to alert on discrepancies. And such validation procedures should do all the calculations, so they might as well populate materialized view.

However, the actual solution depends on frequency you need these data. If you, for example, fetch all the customers balances monthly for invoicing purposes, just don't duplicate them. But if you print the balance after each customer operation, e.g. in some kind of transaction confirmation (like PDF generated and e-mailed to customer), you might want to keep the running balance in a form that was presented to the customer, since he owns the balance evidence.

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. We'd need to keep the data updated following every cost/credit since we bill the user up front rather than at the end of the month. Would you still use materialized views given that?

Comment: No, materialized views would probably be bad idea in such case. I'd go with trigger updating the balance (or partial balances), with some validation/alerting procedure run once a week or so.

Comment: any merit to something like a opening/closing balance approach down the line so we don't have to parse all the records as the user's list of transactions grows?

Comment: It might be worth considering, depending on the per-account volume of operations and database layout itself. For example - it the transaction tables are partitioned monthly, with only the last month kept on faster storage, you might want to have monthly balances fixed and rescan only the current month.